# What is the purpose of the "pass" tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I see there are some questions (182, at this moment) that are tagged [pass](/questions/tagged/pass). Looking at some of those questions, it seems they are completely non-related to each other.

Should the tag be removed, or does it have a specific meaning? In the latter case, what should its tag wiki be?

Comment: It means you shouldn't look at the question.

Comment: In that case, the tag is well ignored. `:-)`

Comment: It looks like a terribly dumb tag and should probably be burninated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's been used in conjunction with [variables](/questions/tagged/variables) and [parameters](/questions/tagged/parameters) a good bit. I can't think of any specific meaning that would justify keeping this tag.

For the sake of being thorough, Wikipedia can't either— the only two remotely programming-related items on the [disambiguation page for "pass"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass) are:

- the [Professional Association for SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Association_for_SQL_Server) (0 search results for ["[pass] + sql + server"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpass%5D%20sql%20server))
- Payments as a Secure Service (0 search results for ["[pass] payments"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpass%5D%20payments))

My guess is it's a meaningless tag that got popular by the way of people using generic words from their question titles as tags.

Also note that [there are no questions that use [pass] as their only tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2005/find-questions-tagged-with-only-the-given-tag?tagname=pass) (as of the last Data Explorer update), so it wouldn't orphan any questions if the tag were nuked.