# Pointless but popular tag 'pass' — can it be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I just came across one of 317 questions with the tag [pass](/questions/tagged/pass).  The tag has no Wiki entry and no followers.  The tag seems to provide no value.  There wasn't much consistency about it (for example, Python has a `pass` statement, but most questions were more about passing data around).

I'd like to recommend that the tag is burninated.

---

I see from the Related list (now the Linked list) that I'm not the first to question the tag:

- [What is the purpose of the "pass" tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112620/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-pass-tag)

The consensus answer back in November 2011 was 'the tag is pointless and should be removed'.

Comment: Only 6 questions that have both `python` and `pass` tags. Only 3 of those are actually about the `pass` statement. Burn!

Comment: Burn [passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passing) as well. I'm only a bit unsure about [parameter-passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameter-passing). Should it be burninated as well? Or should they rather all be synonymized to that one?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: why is the tag 'stackoverflow' important for MSO?  It is the 'meta' for StackOverflow alone, isn't it — not for SU or SF or the multitude of SE sites.  So what does the tag add in the way of information?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, MSO is [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106453/are-meta-stackexchange-and-meta-stackoverflow-one-and-the-same), though [there's a plan to change this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is the meta site for Stack Overflow, and all the Stack Exchange network. [meta-tag:stackoverflow] will be helpful when the questions that are not about Stack Overflow will be migrated to meta.stackexchange.com, which actually points to meta.stackoverflow.com, but which will be an independent site (in future).